# How to sett the HTTP_VERSION in Pycurl for use with Mindtouch CURL interface

Tags: python, pycurl, mindtouch

I am trying to access a Mindtouch Wiki using Python.  I am trying to use pycurl to do this as the sparse Mindtouch documentation does give CURL command line examples.  I found by trial and error that the operation needs the --http1.0 option to be put n the CURL command line in order for the operation to succeed.  However I have not found out how to set this option in pycurl.

What I get is:

```
c.setopt(c.HTTP_VERSION_1_0, True)
AttributeError: trying to obtain a non-existing attribute
```

When using CURL on the command line I use a hand coded XML file and refer to it using the -T option.  However it would be easier to start with the XML as a string.  Any additional insight into doing that in pycurl would be great.

Alternatively, if there is a better way of doing it than pycurl I would be happy to hear of it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTP_VERSION, pycurl.CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0)
```

See curl [official documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION.html).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I looked at the documentation you linked to but this seems to be for the C library.  So you are setting the class variable HTTP_VERSION directly I guess rather than the inherited version in the instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to pycurl, you could try the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) HTTP library.

Here's a working example that gets the JSON output of a specific page.

```
import requests

api_url = "https://success.mindtouch.com/@api/deki/pages/1835/?dream.out.format=json"

response = requests.get(api_url)

print(response.json())
```

This gets the page endpoint for MindTouch's [API calls](https://success.mindtouch.com/Support/Extend/API_Documentation/API_calls) article.

You can also include credentials, like so:

```
import requests

api_url = "https://success.mindtouch.com/@api/deki/pages/1835/?dream.out.format=json"

creds = ("username", "password")
response = requests.get(api_url, auth=creds)

print(response.json())
```